# What is the difference between Confidence intervals and precision intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, psychology, precision

I've tried searching but I cannot even find a definition for a "precision interval" anyway. I am completing a meta-analysis and the package in R that I used to create my figure put both precision and confidence intervals on. The precision intervals stretch longer than the confidence interval's and I have absolutely no idea what they mean. I am not very strong in statistics if it is not clear lol.

I've seen one formula on here explaining it but I don't really understand that and more want to know what the precision interval is conceptually.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I like the term “precision” interval but have never seen it before now. Might you mean a “prediction” interval? If not, what is the source of this “precision” interval? If it is a lecture, might you have misheard the speaker?